# Removing dynamic array element

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have an array of attributes and their values. I also have an array of attributes that I would like removing if present.

```
options.noAttr[0] = "tipref"
```

and `attributes.tipref` would equal the value.

If I wanted to remove `attributes.tipref`, I would have to call it dynamically, looping through the `noAttr`'s, such as

```
attributes.{options.noAttr[i]};
```

Obviously, the above does not work.

Can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This what you want?

```
delete attributes[options.noAttr[i]];
```

In javascript, `array['key']` is the same as `array.key`.